# Telegram bot sendVideo max size

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Im trying to send a video from a bot with a url. i can send a 5mb .mp4 file but 8mb .mp4 doesn't work.

from the telegram bot [api](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendvideo) it says that bots can send videos up to 50mb.

has anyone encountred this?

Comment: could you explain what **doesn't work** means in detail ?

Comment: Yes, of course. I get back : 
'{"ok":false,"error_code":400,"description":"Bad Request: wrong file identifier/HTTP URL specified"}

the URL is correct, it is :[link]http://nba.cdn.turner.com/nba/big/video/2018/03/08/b1c74649-a23e-49ad-b537-d2a191495d27.nba_1973610_480x270_400.mp4

and i send it using post:
'requests.post(URL + 'sendVideo', data=params)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, You can't send video with url if it is bigger than 5mb. Try to send video with Stream.

If you want to send video is bigger than 50mb, you can use custom mtproto server or Telegram Local Server.

Check it: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#using-a-local-bot-api-server